# Get Elementor Submission DB ID

Tags: wordpress, elementor

I am using elementor submissions to collect data from users and I need to show users a reference ID (DB ID of their submission) on Thank You page.

I have set up https://developers.elementor.com/forms-api/#Form_New_Record_Action and have access `Form_Record` class instance but there isn't any method to directly access DB ID. The documentation doesn't provide much detail and I am not even sure if this even provide access to DB ID.

> New Record action

```
add_action( 'elementor_pro/forms/new_record', function( $record, $handler ) {
//make sure its our form
$form_name = $record->get_form_settings( 'form_name' );

// Replace MY_FORM_NAME with the name you gave your form
if ( 'New Form' !== $form_name ) {
    return;
}

$raw_fields = $record->get( 'fields' );
$fields = [];
foreach ( $raw_fields as $id => $field ) {
    $fields[ $id ] = $field['value'];
}
$handler->add_response_data( true, $raw_fields );

}, 10, 2 );
```

> On Submit success event

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    jQuery( document ).ready(function( $ ){
        jQuery( document ).on('submit_success', function(event, response){
            console.log(response.data);
        });
    });
    
</script>
```

Comment: Did you find a way to do this?

Comment: I did but I don't remember how I did.

Comment: A solution is proposed here for anyone else with the same question https://stackoverflow.com/a/78011471/3067126

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of time i thought of digging in the elementor form controllers and i have found right there how it takes the id

```
$ajax_handler->get_current_form()['id'];
```

If anyone gets in this question again with a similar issue the file that saves the elementor form submission is in:

```
elementor-pro/modules/forms/submissions/actions/save-to-database.php
```

Comment: Your answer just returns the form ID, not the submission ID. OP asked for the submission ID.