# Elementor form submission ID in confirmation email

Tags: wordpress, elementor

Each form submission in Elementor gets assinged a unique ID that gets iterated by one for each new submission. I want to reference this ID in the Actions after submit - E-Mail as a way of letting the user know the ID of their request. Is there any way of including this ID as a shortcode in the email that gets sent to the user, to create some sort of ticketing system?

I tried to add the following but it didn't work: `[field id="submission_id"]`
I also read [these]https://elementor.com/help/customizing-form-emails/) Elementor Docs, but they are not very helpful with what I'm trying to achieve.

I think that this requries some custom coding, but I'm unsure where to start.

Answer (score 1):

I found an easy solution for this. I created a short code, that queries the DB table where the submission IDs are stored, extracts the highest value, adds one and returns the value. I then use this short code in the email template that gets sent to the user, and it displays the corresponding submission ID in the E-Mail.

Here is the shortcode:

```html
// Register a function to run on the init hook
add_action( 'init', 'register_get_submission_id_shortcode' );

function register_get_submission_id_shortcode() {
    // Register the get submission id shortcode
    add_shortcode( 'get_submission_id', 'get_submission_id' );
}

function get_submission_id() {
    global $wpdb;

    // Get the highest value from the database table
    $sql = "SELECT MAX(ID) as max_id FROM `hleKsJ9_e_submissions`;";
    $result = $wpdb->get_var( $sql );

    // Add 1 to the highest value and return it
    if ( $result ) {
        return  $result;
    } else {
        return 'No results found';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another method is to obtain the information directly from Elementor itself, if you are comfortable with hacking the plugin core code; adding one line in `plugins/elementor-pro/modules/forms/submissions/actions/save-to-database.php`

In a nutshell; the hack feeds the submission id back to elementor's `$record` object right after the form is saved into the submissions table; during which the id is produced.

```
class Save_To_Database extends Action_Base {
    private $submission_id;
    ...
    public function run( $record, $ajax_handler ) {
        ...
        $this->submission_id = Query::get_instance()->add_submission( [
        ...
        ], $record->get_field( null ) );
        
        // following line does the magic
        $record->set('submission_id', $this->submission_id);
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

Now, the submission id can be consumed in an Elementor hook with `$record->get('submission_id')` - provided the hook is executed after Save_To_Database action; i.e. in `elementor_pro/forms/new_record` hook.

*Do note that, the hack will probably not survive an Elementor Pro update!*